# How to print average time after running 20 @Test methods?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have test which runs and Measures the time of upload.

My task is to run this test 10 times, and print average time out of 10 uploads.
And after 1 run i have 10 @Test executed with 10 separate upload measures.

I rerunning my test just by adding (invocationCount = 10).
Test class consist of

```
@BeforeClass
@Parameters
@Test
@AfterMethod
```

How after each test run i can take a value ( time result) and save it to array?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Comment: Why don't you try to save each run  time in a config file and read it before every run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [inject](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection) a [`ITestResult`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.11-g1e1d341-83/javadoc/org/testng/ITestResult.html) into an `@AfterMethod` and get the time result from there:

```
List<Long> timeResults = ...

@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) {
  timeResults.add(result.getEndMillis() - result.getStartMillis()) 
}
```